# Internationa Grant Fraud scam

Tags: scams

I got an text from a "friend" her photo visible stating she got a substantial amount of money from an international monetary fund project to help seniors, retirees, unemployed, etc.  Just had to answer a few questions. "She" sent a link which I pulled up and answered basic personal questions: name, address, etc. and why I needed the money. I did send my driver's license. A few minutes went by and you would "choose" the amount and what you had to put up front to cover various fees. At that point and realizing the trail of messages from my friend was not the friend I knew I realized it was a scam and stated so.  Arguably, they went on to assure me it was not.  I went no further with it.  I did NOT give out social security info, bank info or credit card info.  How much serious trouble am I in?

Comment: In your country (you didn’t say which), is a driver’s licence a primary form of identification?

Comment: Is your Social Security Number on your driver's license?

Comment: Have your PC scanned for Viruses and Trojans!